# Using CodeMirror component in Vaadin 23

Tags: java, codemirror, vaadin-flow

I need to use a CSS syntax editor which is helping to user to keep the style. Couple of years ago I used the CodeMirror in Javascript and older version of Vaadin successfully. I have tried to integrate the CodeMirror into a new Vaadin application (in v23) but it is working only partially. I'm using 0.19.3 package from basic-setup and lang-css but it appears with initial content but I can not change the content, theme and the functions of editor is not working well (eg. cursor, highlighted row, etc.). Have any of you experience with this kind of integration? I really appreciate any example or use case which will solve this issue.